# Databound ComboBox returns its previous selected item when loosing focus

Tags: data-binding, combobox

I have an ordinary ComboBox on a WinForm. I want to populate it with cities and set its databinding to my Business Object CityID. The object is Office {ID, Name, CityID}
I populate the items like that

```
public void LoadCityCombo(List<City> list)
{
    CityComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    CityComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
    CityComboBox.DataSource = list;
}
```

Than load the object

```
public void LoadOffice(Office office)
{
    NameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", office, "Name");
    AddressTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", office, "Address");
    Binding b = new Binding("SelectedValue", office, "CityID");
    CityComboBox.DataBindings.Add(b);
}
```

The proper city is selected when I open the form but when I select another city from the combo and move to other control (loose combo focus) the old selected city is returned in the combo.

What I'm messing up?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code for other event handlers that might get fired and "mess" things up.

Comment: Hi, there aren't any other event handlers. It is a brand new ComboBox added to the form. Can you post some code that certanly works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this row:

```
Binding b = new Binding("SelectedValue", office, "CityID");
CityComboBox.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

The fix is

```
Binding b = new Binding("SelectedValue", office, "CityID", true);
CityComboBox.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

or

```
Binding b = new Binding("SelectedValue", office, "CityID");
b.FormatingEnabled = true;
CityComboBox.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

I didn't understand if it was caused from my localization, but in another computer the binding worked without setting this property.
The strange thing is that without setting this property you don't have BindingCompleted event fired where you can see if there are binding errors.